# PHP, MySQL: show users 'on leave'

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code below on how to show who is currently "on leave" today.

```
$today = date("j F, Y");//date format is->1 December, 2015
$result = $db->query("SELECT name, date_apply, leave_from, leave_end, num_days, reason FROM applied_user  WHERE status = 'Approved' AND leave_from = '$today'");
```

My question is, is it possible to show all approve leave before the current day?thanks..

Comment: what's your leave_from column type in MYSQL?

Comment: var_char @rain ..thanks

Comment: I usually use int or datetime for calculating time stuff which is easier and faster than var_char.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$today = date('d F, Y'); //current date (11 December, 2015)
$result = $db->query(
    "SELECT name, date_apply, leave_from, leave_end, num_days, reason 
    FROM applied_user  
    WHERE status = 'Approved' 
    AND leave_from >= '$today'");
```

[Phpfiddle Preview](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/f58d255b4b0abfde72bb)

Comment: thanks @Abdulla but my problem is that the date format I must follow is the one I example above..sorry for bad english.

Comment: I'll try this @Abdulla

Comment: Hi @Abdulla, it gives me all the approved leave.

Comment: yes because this in your query `WHERE status = 'Approved' `

Comment: even all the previous date?

Comment: all previous dates means??

Comment: cant unsderstand logic. can you detaul it please

Comment: example: date_apply->1 December, 2015, leave_from-> 10 December, 2015, leave_end-> 12 December, 2015, num_days->3 `status->Approved', I want to show this approve status until 12 December.

Comment: because once the user applied for example today and he/she will be on leave on december 10-december 12, I want to display it in my portal that this person is on leave and visible tomorrow until december 12 only.